# Encouraging users to 'group' very large data sets

Tags: data-tables, data, sort

We have a product that requires users to import large data sets (100+ rows) and then 'group' those datasets into buckets within the product. This is part of the set-up process so that they can start getting value out of our analytics tool.

The first issue we want to address is that users are accidentally creating duplicate buckets with small errors (e.g. spelling or capitalisation inconsistencies). We're exploring a solution that forces users to pre-define the buckets, and then when they're in the bucketing process, only allowing users to select from the pre-defined list of options.

The second issue is that this is inherently a very time-consuming process, and users are not motivated enough to complete the process accurately. I'm wondering what an effective UX solution might be for making this process as quick and easy as possible.

Currently users are given a free text field for each row with which to assign the data to an existing bucket or create a new bucket. They can bulk add rows to the same bucket by selecting each row, or searching for a keyword and then selecting all rows that contain that keyword. This solution works OK but it feels like there might be a faster and more intuitive option out there.

Has anyone dealt with a similar requirement and found a strong solution?

Comment: This probably is a few months long work, I doubt anyone can answer this here with the data available since it will depend on A LOT of user research. Anyway, interested to see if there any answers